# Interpret bash escape sequences and other characters using ncurses

Tags: linux, c, ncurses, pty

I want to design a terminal multiplexer like `tmux`, but not that complex, something minimal, that works remote, using `ncurses`.

On the server side, the workflow is as follows:

- The server process creates in total 2 processes: the first process will be `fork`ed from the parent and will `forkpty` the second process. The `forkpty`ed process will `execl` a bash shell. The first process will talk to the second process using the descriptor returned by the `forkpty()` call. The first process will also communicate with the client. It will be like a middleman. It will pass what's coming from the client to the `forkpty`ed process and vice-versa.

On the client side, the workflow is as follows:

- The client will create a thread which will be responsible with talking to the server. Inside the thread will run `ncurses`.

The problem is that `ncurses` doesn't parse the escape sequences coming from bash nor other special characters. I've took 2 screenshots (this is on the client side). In the first one the information received from server (the output of commands ran in the shell) is displayed onto the standard output using the `write()` syscall. In the second screenshot, the information is displayed on `stdscr` using the `printw` function. That's the only difference in code between the 2 screenshots.

I need that `printw` function because I want to split the terminal onto multiple windows. How can I make `ncurses` interpret those sequences (and those special characters) without too much of a hassle? The screenshots can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K96HZ.jpg).

P.S: I'm not that advanced to understand `tmux`'s source code fully or even partly.